# How to catch eval failed racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

the documentation says `eval` return `any`... I have a case that have to know whether `eval` failed or not.. How to test this?

Comment: Like normal I guess, with an exception handler (`guard` or what ever it is called in Racket).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like @leppie said, you just do it as usual.  Here's an example:

```
(define (eval* expr)
  (with-handlers ([exn? (λ (e) `(fail ,(exn-message e)))])
    `(success ,(eval expr))))
```

See also the [sandbox library](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Sandboxed_Evaluation.html) for much more control over evaluation, and (as always) beware of the [usual subtelties](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html) that come with using `eval`.

Comment: Thanks!! Code explains all! especially for someone who has never used it before:)

Comment: Oh...should `[exn? (  (e) `(fail ,(exn-message e)))]` be `[exn? ( lambda (e) `(fail ,(exn-message e)))]`? otherwise, the `e` is unbounded identifier?

Comment: @Jenny: Yeah, that was a bad copy+paste of a unicode lambda...  Fixed now.